# Remover dificuldade de senha do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Tentei remover a dificuldade para escrever uma senha no wordpress, utilizo o plugin ultimate members para fazer o cadastro, utilizei o código abaixo para solucionar o problema, porém não consegui.

```
    function iconic_remove_password_strength() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'iconic_remove_password_strength', 10 );
```

Tentei este também:

```
function wc_ninja_remove_password_strength() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_ninja_remove_password_strength', 100 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Cara, voce mesmo ja botou a resposta
Poe essa função na pasta raiz do seu projeto que vai dar tudo certo

```js
function wc_ninja_remove_password_strength() {
 if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
  wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
 }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wc_ninja_remove_password_strength', 100 );
```